# my python is confusing the minus with dash sign

Tags: python

I am trying to run the following python with *" python get_timestamp.py -f gsham_input.xvg -1 −0.1348  -2 −0.1109"*. However, it seems that the python is mistaking the minus sign before the decimals with the dash sign and shows this error: "File "get_timestamp.py", line 21, in 
    value1 = float(arg)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): −0.1348
"
Could you please help me know how to resolve it?

Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Given two values, looks in a 3 column-file (output of sham.pl)
which time frame matches closest.
"""

import sys

USAGE = "USAGE: get_timestamp.py -f <sham output> -1 <value 1> -2 <value 2>\n"

# Parse arguments
read_input, read_value1, read_value2 = False, False, False
input_file, value1, value2 = None, None, None
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    if read_input:
        read_input = False
        input_file = arg
    elif read_value1:
        read_value1 = False
        value1 = float(arg)
    elif read_value2:
        read_value2 = False
        value2 = float(arg)
    if arg[0] == "-":
        if arg == "-f":
            read_input = True
            continue
        elif arg == "-1":
            read_value1 = True
            continue
        elif arg == "-2":
            read_value2 = True
        else:
            print USAGE
            sys.stderr.write('ERROR: Option not recognized: %s\n' %arg)
            sys.exit(1)

if not input_file:
    print USAGE
    sys.stderr.write('ERROR: You forgot to provide an input file.\n')
    sys.exit(1)

# Open sham output
x_values, y_values, time_values = [], [], []
fhandle = open(input_file)
for line in fhandle:
    if line[0] != "#" and len(line.split()) == 3:
        t,x,y = line.split()
        x_values.append(float(x))
        y_values.append(float(y))
        time_values.append(float(t))
fhandle.close()

def find_common_frame(min_x, min_y):
    for xval in min_x:
        xframe = xval[0]
        for yval in min_y:
            yframe = yval[0]
            if xframe == yframe:
                return (xframe, xval[1], yval[1])
    return (None, None, None)

# If you cannot find anything, try increasing the nval variable
nval = 50
min_x = sorted(enumerate(x_values), key=lambda x: abs(x[1]-value1))[:nval]
min_y = sorted(enumerate(y_values), key=lambda x: abs(x[1]-value2))[:nval]

frame, x, y = find_common_frame(min_x, min_y)

if not frame:
    print "No timestamp found.."
    sys.exit(0)
print "## T = %s (%s, %s)" %(time_values[frame], x, y)
```

Comment: From looking at the formatting of your post, it appears that you are using two different dashes (is one an M-dash?)

Comment: this isn't a very pythonic way to parse args, use the `argparse` module instead

Comment: Honestly I am not very familiar with python and need to work with python as a part of my analysis. Do you have any suggestions to edit it?

Comment: @Chris_Rands `docopt` for the win. Seriously, I fell in love with that module, I don't ever want to go back to `argparse`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a Python problem, the float numbers that you are passing begin with [minus signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs#Minus_sign) (`−`, unicode U+2212) instead of [regular hyphens-minus symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus) (`-`, unicode U+002D, the ones used by Python and most languages as "minus" sign). I'd guess it's because you copied the numbers from some document, since it is rather hard to type a Unicode minus sign with a keyboard.

The easy solution is to replace these signs with regular hyphens when you call the program in the command line. If you *really* need you program to work with these signs, you could use a function like this to parse the numbers instead of calling `float`:

```
def float_unicode(arg_str):
    return float(arg_str.decode("utf8").replace(u"\u2212", "-"))
```

However I wouldn't recommend this, as it just complicates the program more  and most command line tools that work with numbers do not support this, so users generally won't expect your program to do so.

Comment: I am not sure how to use "minus sign" and "regular hyphen" with the keyword. Could you give me a clue?

Comment: @Sajad What do you mean with "the keyword" (a typo for "the keyboard")? What I suggest is that you simply replace `−0.1348` with `-0.1348` (and so on) in the command line before calling your program. Or just write the numbers with they keyboard instead of copy and pasting them. The "regular hyphen" (the one that you need) is the one you get when you press the minus or hyphen key on your keyboard.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I used the "regular hyphen" (the key on the left side of 0 on the keyboard) before all the options and numbers in my command (python get_timestamp.py -f gsham_input.xvg -1  -0.1348 -2  -0.1109). However, I encountered this error "ERROR: Option not recognized: -0.1348". Am I missing something?

Comment: @Sajad That is a different problem. Your logic interprets that any parameter starting with `-` is an option, so negative numbers get mistaken by these. You can redesign your argument parsing code or, as has been suggested in the comments, use a more solid solution like [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/argparse.html).

Comment: Thanks. I changed the - to + in the parsing code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3

```
float_num_of_str = float(arg_str.replace(u"\u2212", "-"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, later realize that I used the dash in my keyboard instead of the minus sign located in the numeric side of the keyboard.

While using sublimetext notice there is a difference in color

when you use the dash and the minus sign on the numeric keyboard side,

the dash appears in color **WHITE** while the minus sign appears in **RED**.