# Converting String to Float in matplotlib generates Error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to convert some numbers represented as strings but I get an error!

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.linspace(-np.pi*2, np.pi*2, 200)
b = np.cos(a)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(a, b)

fig.canvas.draw()

labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]

labels = [float(label) for label in labels]

float(labels[-1]) # this works
```

> *error :
>   labels = [float(label) for label in labels]
>   ValueError: could not convert string to float: '−8'*

`labels`, in this case, can be generated as `[str(i) for i in range(-8, 9, 2)]` which I can convert its items to float but not the text of the label retrieved from matplotlib!

I believe the issue is with the `-` sign.

since when i check 
`'-8' in labels` gives False

but `'8' in labels` gives True

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to replace the unicode character U+002D to U+2212. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45631300/12098253) can help you with that. But it also says that it's not very recomended. You can use instead `ax.get_xticks()`

```
print(ax.get_xticks())
output : [-8. -6. -4. -2.  0.  2.  4.  6.  8.]
```

Answer (score 1):

> I believe the issue is with the `-` sign.

It is, sort of. The problem is that in the string that could not be converted, the character in front of the '8' is not an ASCII hyphen (with Unicode codepoint U+002D) but rather the Unicode character for a minus sign (with Unicode codepoint U+2212). Those characters look very similar, but Python only treats the first one as a minus sign.

Comment: do you have any idea how can I convert it to an understandable minus sign for python

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti The `replace` method for strings should do it, something like `label.replace("\u2212", "-")`. But I think Gabriel's answer is better.