# Issue in character identifier for abs() in map() Python

Tags: python, dictionary, character, identifier

Here the only one problem:

```
list(map(abs, [−1, −2, 0, 1, 2]))
                ^
invalid character in identifier
```

abs should do it in right way, but map had a problem. So, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the Unicode [minus sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs#Minus_sign) ("−"; U+2212) instead of the [hyphen-minus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus) ("-"; U+002D) that Python (and most other programming languages) recognize.

Just replace the minus signs with regular dashes, and the problem should go away.

If you need to do this across a large amount of data that you're copying from elsewhere, a simple string replacement (similar to the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45631300/7389264)) before you parse the data should do the job:

```
with open(infilename, 'r') as infile, open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line.replace('\N{MINUS SIGN}', '-'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you were wrong or badly copied the example, what happens is that the character that looked like it was a negative sign (-) was another character and read it as if it was not that negative sign
Here I leave it corrected.

```
list(map(abs, [-1, -2, 0, 1, 2]))
```

Good luck!

Comment: hehe.. we have read same book

Comment: https://books.google.com.bo/books?id=1HxWGezDZcgC&pg=PA503&lpg=PA503&dq=list(map(abs,+%5B%E2%88%921,+%E2%88%922,+0,+1,+2%5D))&source=bl&ots=LlLfXOhcq-&sig=ACfU3U0dN5ZtXxe-5jpIxQN690ZKEGym_A&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ37Wd8LvlAhVKIbkGHSfWBOcQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=list(map(abs%2C%20%5B%E2%88%921%2C%20%E2%88%922%2C%200%2C%201%2C%202%5D))&f=false